# Windows 8 Installation couldn't find drives

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I am trying to install Windows on Ubuntu using a bootable Windows USB stick. Basically I want to multi boot with Ubuntu and Windows 8. However, on the "Where do you want to install Windows?" installation windows, it doesn't show any available drives. ! 
[No visible drives in the windows 8 installation -

[image]

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Use a boot usb with ubuntu and gparted installed to resize your ubuntu partition, leaving unallocated the ammount of space you want to use for windows 8. Boot from the windows 8 usb to install it on the empty space. Boot back into ubuntu using the boot usb, install boot repair on it, run it to fix grub and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better before to start to install Windows to make from Ubuntu a NTFS partition with [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/). Normally, Windows does not see Linux partitions and because of this you don't have visible drives in the Windows installation.